# "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo" BinaryXML Error

Tags: android

```
When I run my application I got the following errors:

    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.siddhu.user.shapes, PID: 13878
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.siddhu.user.shapes/com.siddhu.user.shapes.Shapes_2d}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #21: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #21: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:606)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6472)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6641)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1864)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1776)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:62)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:808)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.siddhu.user.shapes.Shapes_2d.onCreate(Shapes_2d.java:22)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
    11-04 15:47:11.808 13878-13878/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 




I check my xml and java class i did not find any mistake.  I think I am doing no mistake in xml file and can any one solve this issue? I registered the all the classes in android manifest file. I don't know where the error was raising.

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/subpage01_bg"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="2D Shapes"
            android:textSize="72dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/subpage_ele_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/subpage_ele_height"
            android:id="@+id/subpg1_ele"
            android:src="@drawable/subpage01_3d_ele"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/shapes3d_linearlayout_width"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/shapes3d_linearlayout_height">



            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/shapes3d_cube_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/shapes3d_cube_height"
                android:src="@drawable/subpage01_circle"
                android:stateListAnimator="@anim/raise"
                android:id="@+id/cicle"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/shapes3d_text_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/shapes3d_text_height"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="   Circle"

                    android:textSize="35dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/shapes3d_linearlayout_width"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/shapes3d_linearlayout_height">



                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/shapes3d_cube_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/shapes3d_cube_height"
                    android:src="@drawable/subpage01_square"
                    android:stateListAnimator="@anim/raise"
                    android:id="@+id/rectangle"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/shapes3d_text_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/shapes3d_text_height"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Rectangle"

                    android:textSize="30dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/shapes3d_linearlayout_width"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/shapes3d_linearlayout_height">



                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/shapes3d_cube_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/shapes3d_cube_height"
                    android:stateListAnimator="@anim/raise"
                    android:src="@drawable/subpage01_triangle"

                    android:id="@+id/triangle"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/shapes3d_text_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/shapes3d_text_height"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Triangle"

                    android:textSize="35dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

following is my dimens.xml can any one solve and explain the issue.for future
 references.  and i think i defined all attributes regarding layout and textviews and all other views properly. and some one said remove weight sums in your layout. is it causes the crash or not i dont know.plz any one help my problem.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">64dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">72dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="mainpg_imgbtn_text">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mainpg_text_width">360dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mainpg_text_height">120dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mainpage_imgbtn_height">150dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mainpage_imgbtn_width">150dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mainpage_linearlayout_height">200dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mainpage_animation_image_height">120dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mainpage_animation_image_width">120dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mainpage_imgbtn_text_height">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mainpage_imgbtn_text_width">150dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mainpg_headtext_size">96dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mainpg_bird_width">250dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mainpg_bird_height">250dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="subpage_ele_width">200dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="subpage_ele_height">200dp</dimen>


    <dimen name="shapes3d_cube_width">150dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="shapes3d_cube_height">150dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="shapes3d_rab_height">250dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="shapes3d_rab_width">250dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="shapes3d_rab_marginleft">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="shapes3d_text_width">150dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="shapes3d_text_height">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="shapes3d_home_margintop">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="shapes3d_linearlayout_height">200dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="shapes3d_linearlayout_width">200dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="circles_around_text_height">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="circles_around_text_width">320dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="circles_around_text_size">64dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="circles_around_linearlayout_width">600dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="circles_around_linearlayout_height">150dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="circles_around_image_width">150dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="circles_around_image_height">150dp</dimen>


    <dimen name="drag_and_drop_image_width">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="drag_and_drop_image_height">100dp</dimen>


    <dimen name="oddone_image_width">64dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="oddone_image_height">64dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="games_image_width">64dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="games_image_height">64dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="games_linearlayout_width">300dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="games_linearlayout_height">300dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="games_marginleft">-72dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="tap_image_width">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tap_image_height">80dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tap_linearlayout_width">600dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="tap_linearlayout_height">100dp</dimen>



    <dimen name="subpage2_linearlayout_height">250dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="sp2menu">75dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="sp2back">75dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="sp2home">75dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="sp4_imageview_height">200dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="sp4_imageview_width">200dp</dimen>






</resources>
```

Comment: Please show dimen.xml also

Comment: Have you defined the proper dimen values? `"@dimen/shapes3d_text_width"` and others

Comment: i defined proper values check once again my dimens.xml .i posted below

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/shapes3d_linearlayout_width"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="2"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/shapes3d_linearlayout_height">
```

in all layout set width and hight as wrap/match/fill watever u wants but not in dimens

Comment: can i know the  what happen when define dimensions @Shivanshu

Answer (score -1):

Delete all weightSum's, you are not using them, then check that all the @dimen values exists and are ok.